# Microsoft Forms - Need to branch a form's Submit button

Tags: microsoft-forms

We've got a Microsoft Forms page which asks users a handful of screening questions.

Depending on a user's responses, they may become ineligible to proceed to the next stage of our process, which includes a Microsoft Bookings appointment. We **must** keep that Bookings URL secret from folks who are ineligible.

Any thoughts on how we can use Forms' branching logic to route ineligible users to a completely different outcome?

Comment: Dan, Welcome! In the Add_Click event for the submit button include the appropriate logic. If you tell us what language you are using for to call the form maybe we can provide an example.

Comment: Hey thanks @RetiredGeek - that was enough to point the team's devs in the right direction!